# How to access a .jar present inside of a .war from some other .war?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, weblogic, war

Suppose i have a .war file which includes a Jar file(WEB-INF\lib), Now i want to access this jar from some other war file. is this possible without placing it at some common reference. All Suggestions welcomed.

Comment: You'll need to place the common *.jar* file in a shared location.  For security reasons, servlet containers generally try to keep the class loaders for different *.war* files separate, so it would be somewhat painful to get around this.

Comment: You have to either define the JAR as an EAR library and the WARs as modules of the EAR application. Or you can define the JAR file as a Shared Library and then reference from any WAR/EAR file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a ear and within the two war. The jar willl be placed in the lib folder of the ear and can be accessed by both.